# java swt image (imagedata) rotation

Tags: java, image, swt, rotation

I'm trying to do a simple program, where I can add some png's to canvas.
One of the option is to rotate selected png. I have problem with rotation.
When I'm using Transformation it rotates everything on canvas.
I founded only examples of rotation by 90' or flip but I want to rotate by any angle.

I was also trying to convert swt image to bufferedimage, rotate then convert bufferedimage to swt image and draw it but it's very slow and having some problems with transparency.

I'm will be gratefull for help - I want to rotate via center of image.
For drawig I'm using GC and Canvas - new GC(canvas);

---

**EDIT:**
I stil have problem with rotation by center of image:

```
gc.setAdvanced(true);
        if (!gc.getAdvanced()) {
            gc.drawText("Advanced graphics not supported", 30, 30, true);
            return;
        }

        Transform oldTransform = new Transform(gc.getDevice());  
        gc.getTransform(oldTransform);

        Transform transform = new Transform(GCController.getCanvas().getDisplay());
        transform.translate(width/2, height/2);
        transform.rotate(rotation);
        gc.setTransform(transform);
        gc.drawImage(image, x, y);

        gc.setTransform(oldTransform);

        transform.dispose();
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use matrix transformations. Have a look at [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet207.java?view=co) SWT snippet. For reference I have shown the 15 degree as example (towards the end).

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class ImageTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();

        final Image image = new Image(display,"next.png");


        final Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Matrix Tranformations");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener () {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {    
                GC gc = e.gc;
                gc.setAdvanced(true);
                if (!gc.getAdvanced()){
                    gc.drawText("Advanced graphics not supported", 30, 30, true);
                    return;
                }

                // Original image
                int x = 30, y = 30;
                gc.drawImage(image, x, y); 
                x += rect.width + 30;

                Transform transform = new Transform(display);

                // Note that the tranform is applied to the whole GC therefore
                // the coordinates need to be adjusted too.

                // Reflect around the y axis.
                transform.setElements(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0);
                gc.setTransform(transform);
                gc.drawImage(image, -1*x-rect.width, y);



                // Rotate by 45 degrees 
                float cos45 = (float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4);
                float sin45 = (float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4);
                transform.setElements(cos45, sin45, -sin45, cos45, 0, 0);
                gc.setTransform(transform);
                gc.drawImage(image, x , y);

                float cos15 = (float)Math.cos(Math.PI/12);
                float sin15 = (float)Math.sin(Math.PI/12);
                transform.setElements(cos15, sin15, -sin15, cos15, 0, 0);
                gc.setTransform(transform);
                gc.drawImage(image, x+rect.width/2 , y+rect.height/2);

                transform.dispose();
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(350, 550);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        image.dispose();
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

**>>Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved it.

```
gc.setAdvanced(true);
        if (!gc.getAdvanced()) {
            gc.drawText("Advanced graphics not supported", 30, 30, true);
            return;
        }

        Transform oldTransform = new Transform(gc.getDevice());  
        gc.getTransform(oldTransform);

        Transform transform = new Transform(GCController.getCanvas().getDisplay());
        transform.translate(x+width/2, y+height/2);
        transform.rotate(rotation);
        transform.translate(-x-width/2, -y-height/2);

        gc.setTransform(transform);
        gc.drawImage(image, x, y);          
        gc.setTransform(oldTransform);

        transform.dispose();
```

The problem was in a bad translation. So first I had to translate my shape by it's x and y position plus half of width and length and after rotation back to previous position:

first translation:

```
transform.translate(x+width/2, y+height/2);
```

then rotation and second translation:

```
transform.translate(-x-width/2, -y-height/2);
```